# Should I focus on responsivity or functionality on my first Android APP

Tags: android, responsive

I'm developing an Android app and I'm not sure how my workflow should be.

Should I focus on functionality, I mean, only one screen size device and then adapt the app to others screen sizes.

Or should I focus on responsivity at the same time I work on functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you are new to android development. Initially when you start with your development, your primary focus should be on grasping things up. The more you grasp things, the more you are able think. Secondly, **you should be keep your main focus on functionality of app.**
When you start building apps, they should at-least have utility. A user, downloads app from playstore if and only if, the app is working. Designing is a secondary thing. You will get designers for sure, but the main approach of an android developer who is just getting started, should be the working of an App